# How to select different database at runtime in hibernate

Tags: java

I am developing web application which is in hibernate and spring . There are different database for each user.I have to select it in such a way that if user login it should select database which is accessible only by that particular user

Comment: There will be two sessionfactories, based on the logedin user information, you need to select a session factory and perform all the database operation on it.

Comment: suppose i have n-number of user then i'll have to create n-number session factory for each user

Comment: Well, your application design looks really wierd, why will you need so many databases? can you please elaborate more on the requirement?

Comment: Actually my requirement is that in single domain i'm creating 3 to 4 different application which refer to same url only but i have to store information of user in different database based on different application of that particular user

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? SQL Server? "*selecting a different database*" has a **very** different meaning in different DBMS

Comment: as of now  i am using two database like mysql & oracle

Comment: Just have two session factories for `oracle` and `mysql`, set properties runtime time to deal with different databases.